# How to keep object type for smart casting when returning Any

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Apologies if this is a silly question, Kotlin is still new to me and I'm unfamiliar with syntax "types" so found it difficalt to find the solution.

```
fun Any?.test(): Any?
{
    return this
}

"test string".test() // implicit string is now type of "Any"
"test string".test().substring() // what i'm trying to achieve
```

I basically want the class extension method to return its own instance so I can still operate on it as per the bottom line of the example

Excuse the crassness of the example, was simplified down

Comment: What exactly is the test function supposed to do?

Comment: Log out any object regardless of type to the console to also allow for chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your extension function generic, then it should work.

```
fun <T> T?.test(): T?
{
    return this
}
```

Comment: Using `T?` will mean that this will _always_ return a nullable type. If you replace `T?` with `T` then it will only return a nullable type if `T` is nullable.

Comment: This answer is somewhat less correct than @zsmb13's

Comment: surely not returning `T?` means that the compiler doesnt know if the result *could* be null, which is what I want hence this accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [generic function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions):

```
fun <T> T.test(): T {
    return this
}
```